# Do I have to reconfigure wamp after reinstall?

Tags: configuration, installation, wamp

Really sorry if this is a stupid question.
I installed wamp a year ago or something and now they have newer version so I am thinking of installing it.
I am just wondering should I uninstall the old wamp first or I don't have to that I can just install the new wamp and let the installation replace the files.
Also after installing the new wamp, do I have to reconfigure everything again? Such as httpd.config, the port, vhost and all others?

Comment: Save your old httpd.conf file, my.ini, and other configuration files. Some things change in those config files from version to version. You'll need to consult Apache and MySQL for details specific to your version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy non destructive process to install a new version of WAMPServer which does not actually destroy your current version and allows you to move your current versions of Apache/MySQL and PHP to the newly installed WAMPServer.

I dont have the time to convert the instructions to SO format, so I'm afraid I am just going to give you a link [Installing a new release of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

Comment: ah thanks. I didn't try yet but this question came through my head and of course will do that later in the future since it's always good to be updated.